Brand new battery but only starts with jumping it
My car 2012 Hyundai sonata limited has a brand new battery. The car would only start if I jumped it and would stay running until I turned it off. For a while I would hve to take the battery clamps off and clean them and it started right up and now it don't start. One of the clamps are a little bent could it be the cables or the clamps?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the voltage at the battery without the engine running?

No I'm gonna do that in the morning

It's great to replace the battery terminals if they're corroded, super cheap and they do improve conductivity. Otherwise, most batteries are not sold fully charged. Has driving around a bit resolved the issue? Also why did you replace the battery initially and was the alternator checked at that time?
